# After npm install tachyons, tachyons package not added in package.json?

Tags: reactjs, tachyons-css

npm install output:

```
npm WARN afterxii@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN afterxii@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ tachyons@4.11.1
updated 1 package and audited 518 packages in 5.404s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

How can it be added in package.json

Comment: The command I used was 'npm install tachyons'. I ran the same command, in a new terminal tab and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the command you're executing.

However, I assume that you executed `npm install`. To add a package to dependencies you should do `npm install --save` or `npm install --save-dev`.

More info in the documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install